# scroll image horizontally with sensors

Tags: android, android-sensors, horizontalscrollview

Using the Android Motion Sensors, I want to scroll an Image horizontally with the sensors. My images are larger than the screen so I set the image at his centercrop and then scroll horizontally moving the device left to right.
Unfortunately it doesn't scroll properly. Which sensor should I use ? Gyroscope or accelerometer ? And how to move on the x-axis properly ?

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
private HorizontalScrollView hview;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
    hview = (HorizontalScrollView) this.findViewById(R.id.hview);
    hview.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);

}


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE){
        float xAxis = sensorEvent.values[0];
        hview.scrollTo((int)xAxis*100, 100);

    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
}



@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

}

layout

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/hview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```